# Android Maps v2 API...How to calculate distance between two locations (Lat, long)

Tags: android-maps-v2

In my "native" Android app I'm trying to calculate the distance in feet and/or meters (as the crow flies) between two locations on a map. Ideally there would be a method that would take two LatLng values (as that is what I have readily available) as input and return the distance in meters and/or yards. As noted above I'm using Android Maps v2 API.

I've looked at MANY postings (20-30) regarding calculating distances and haven't found any that have helped me resolve my issue. Again this is a native Android application and I'm using Maps v2 API.

Not sure if this is the best approach but I'm currently trying to use the `Location` method:

```
distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

But unfortunately the app crashes every time because I get a null value for results. I have verified via the debugger that the latitude and longitude dummy values that I'm passing in are valid and that the value of `results` is null (hence the problem). Here is the LogCat:

```
04-04 23:48:04.770: D/onMapClick(17970): lat/lng: (32.90843038503306,-117.22537234425546)
04-04 23:48:08.710: D/dalvikvm(17970): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
04-04 23:48:08.710: D/dalvikvm(17970): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7010 objects / 641712 bytes in 121ms
04-04 23:48:24.980: D/AndroidRuntime(17970): Shutting down VM
04-04 23:48:24.980: W/dalvikvm(17970): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020950)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: results is null or has length < 1
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at android.location.Location.distanceBetween(Location.java:394)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.example.googleplacesandmaps.PlacesMapActivity$1.onMapClick(PlacesMapActivity.java:259)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$6.onMapClick(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.t$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:249)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IOnMapClickListener$Stub$Proxy.onMapClick(IOnMapClickListener.java:93)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at maps.i.s.b(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at maps.y.v.c(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at maps.y.bf.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at maps.d.v.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at maps.d.j.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
04-04 23:48:25.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the method I'm currently using to try and calculate the distance:

```
            Location.distanceBetween(Double.parseDouble(user_latitude), Double.parseDouble(user_longitude),
                fxdLatitude, fxdLongitude, results);
```

The `results` was defined as a Class variable:  `private float[] results = null;`

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Again I'd rather have a method that would take two LatLng's as input parameters because they are both readily available...but perhaps more importantly I only have one of the locations available as separate Longitude, Latitude values...the second location is only available as a LatLng value because I get it via onMapClick (when user taps screen). So to use the method `distanceBetween` I'd need someway to convert this LatLng value into a Latitude/Longitude pair to be able to use it. Anybody know how to do that?

Hopefully there is a simple way of calculating the distances and a simple way to "extract" the latitude/longitude from a LatLng value.

Answer (score 14):

What about making Location object from the two ?

```
private float distanceBetween(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {

        Location loc1 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location loc2 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        loc1.setLatitude(latLng1.latitude);
        loc1.setLongitude(latLng1.longitude);

        loc2.setLatitude(latLng2.latitude);
        loc2.setLongitude(latLng2.longitude);


        return loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to convert the latitude and longitude since they are in micro degrees?

Comment: if they are not in float format (like 27.132235 ), they have to be converted.

Comment: You may consider voting the answer up if you think it's useful :).

Answer (score 3):

You can use following function that accepts two LatLng for calculating distance between them. But before you use this make sure your LatLng variables are not null.

> ```
> public static double distance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
>     double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
>     double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
>     double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
>     double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
>     double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
>     double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
>     double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
>     Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
>     Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
>     double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
>     return 6366000 * c;
> }
> ```

Comment: @KetanMehta If you mean radius of the visible area, you can get the viewport via LatLngBounds bbox = GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds. Afterwards just use Sharj distance calc method to get the distance between bbox.southwest and bbox.northeast (what would be the diameter of the viewport).

Answer (score 1):

`private float[] results = null;` is wrong.

You need to use `private float[] results = new float[1];` and read the distance with `results[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin**, you can:

Define a method to convert `LatLng` to `Location`:

```
fun LatLng.toLocation() = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).also {
    it.latitude = latitude
    it.longitude = longitude
}
```

Call it on each `LatLng` and use `Location#distanceTo(...)` method:

```
val distance = coords1.toLocation().distanceTo(coords2.toLocation())
```

Define an extension method for `LatLngBounds`:

```
fun LatLngBounds.computeDistance(): Float {
    return northeast.toLocation().distanceTo(southwest.toLocation())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think MaciejGórski is right.

The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].